# How to plot one line in a multiple lines plot with a special format

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to plot `line a` as solid (in this example it is solid by chance) and without shape points. I tried to use `scale_linetype_manual(values=c("?", "solid", "?"))` and `scale_shape_manual(values=c(?, ?, ?))` but I don't know how to solve the following:

1. What is the value for "no point" in a scale_shape?;
2. Most of the time I have not only 3 lines but several different numbers of lines and only one of them has a special format (solid and with no point shape).

```
    library(tidyverse)
    df <- tibble(d = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3),
                 name = c('a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c'),
                 year = c(2010, 2011, 2012, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2010, 2011, 2012),
                 value = c(0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.5,0.4,0.3))

    ggplot(data = df, aes(x = year, y = value)) +
      geom_line(aes(color = name, linetype = name), size = 1) +
      geom_point(aes(shape = name, color = name), size = 2) +
      scale_color_discrete(guide = guide_legend(ncol = 2)) +
      theme_bw() +
      theme(axis.text.x=element_text(size=rel(1.5), angle=90),
            axis.text.y=element_text(size=rel(1.5)),
            legend.title=element_blank(),
            legend.text=element_text(size=rel(1.2)),
            legend.position = "bottom",
            axis.line = element_line(color = 'black'),
            panel.border = element_blank(),
            panel.background = element_blank(),
            panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
            panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank()) +
      scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(2010, 2012, by = 1)) +
      labs(
        title = "Chart title",
        x = NULL,
        y = "No."
      ) +
      ylim(0, 1)
```

Comment: Is this similar to what you are looking for? https://gist.github.com/ateucher/7953412

Comment: I got this error: Error in `[[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, i, value = c(0, 1, 1)) : 
  replacement has 3 rows, data has 2
In addition: Warning message:
In geom_abline(intercept = 10, slope = -0.1, aes(colour = "Linear")) :
  Using `intercept` and/or `slope` with `mapping` may not have the desired result as mapping is overwritten if either of these is specified

Comment: Since point shapes can take characters as their shape, the following works for hiding one point type `+ scale_shape_manual(values = list("", 16, 17))`